# What + sb + verb + [be (in the appropriate tense)] is followed by to + infinitive or a gerund?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

When we have a sentence of the form: *What + sb + **verb** + [be (in the appropriate tense)] + ...* (for instance, what I like is ...), which rules do we have to apply to determine whether the sentence is followed by to + infinitive or a gerund? Are these rules the same ones that we use when deciding if the **verb** is followed by to + infinitive or a gerund?

Comment: Either can work, e.g. "What I like is to eat at home" or "What I like is eating at home".

Answer (score 1):

Turn it around to understand it:

To eat at home is what I like.=
What I like is to eat at home.

Eating at home is what I like. =
I like eating at home.

The infinitive implies you like the idea. The second implies you enjoy the action of doing so. That is the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

(what-cleft or pseudo-cleft)

This one is used to emphasize.

I liked to have a talk with her on the phone.

What I liked was (to) have a talk with her on the phone.

If you want to emphasize the verb "have", you can omit "to".

You can use to-infinitive or infinitive itself.

This is just a some high level grammar.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that writing the sentence in this form (What + sb + verb + ...) does not change the rules of to + inf/ gerund. For instance, we know that suggest goes followed by a gerund, therefore "What I suggest is..." must go followed by a gerund too. Another question, could we say: "What I liked was having a talk with her on the phone"?

Comment: You could find the answer to your question in what I've already said above.

Comment: But what about using the gerund in your sentence?